# Removing rows from dataframe which don't contain a string of a certain length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe which contains a column with strings of the form XXX/XX/XXX. I want to remove all rows for which the length of the string between the '/'s is not equal to two.

I'm getting a "key error: True" with the following code:

```
df_issues = df_new[len(df_new['Job'].str.split('/')[1]) != 2 ]
```

My approach was to create a series with all rows for which the string length after the first '/' was not equal to 2.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things you have wrong here:

- `len(x) != 2` will return a boolean. i.e. you're trying to index with `df_new[True]`, which returns a key error, since the shapes are not compatible (you want an indexing array along the rows, something like `df_new[[True, False, True...]]`)
- You need the `str` accessor again to further index on the second list

---

Use instead:

```
df_new[df_new['Job'].str.split(r'/').str[1].str.len().eq(2.)]
```

Or we could also use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
# corrected with @jon's remarks
df_new[df_new['Job'].str.contains(r'^.{3}/.{2}/.{3}$',na=False)]
```

Comment: `{0,2}` seems a little flexible here... it should probably be `{2}` to be exactly two and since we don't know what the X's are supposed to represent - `\d` might be a little too strict. And if doing contains might as well validate the whole pattern  - maybe: `^.{3}/.{2}/.{3}$`

Comment: Agree with both your remarks. Indeed it should be `{2}`, I read that part wrong @jon

Comment: Otherwise... `/////blah///xx////hello!` will match

Comment: RIght, I went to fast on that one... :) @jon